# Can you rename product image filename via Rest Api?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, media, magento2.1.6, media-images

I'm trying to rename product image via rest API.

So far I got the error

> Cannot save product

on PUT `/V1/products/{sku}/media/{entryId}`

Here is roughly the last thing i tried

```
{
  "entry": {
    "id":id,
    "media_type": "image",
    "file": "wutever-image",
    "content": {
        "name": "wutever-image"
    }
    }
 }
```

If I eliminate the **"file"** key, there is no error but nothing changed in the product itself